# True boolean while statements not exiting loops in nested ifs

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, nested

When I set while1 = false inside of a loop where the value of while1 was true and the loops condition is while(while1) it should exit the loops. In nested if statements it doesn't seem to do this, though.

```
package javanotes;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EggsCount {

    static Scanner var1 = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main (String[] args){    

        int eggNumber;
        int eggsGross;
        int eggsDozen;
        int eggsSingle;
        int eggsGrossRemainder;
        int eggsDozenRemainder;
        boolean while1 = true;
        boolean while2 = true;

        System.out.println("How many eggs do you have?");
        eggNumber = var1.nextInt();

        while (while1){
            if (eggNumber > 144){
                eggsGross = eggNumber / 144;
                eggsGrossRemainder = eggNumber % 144;

                if(eggsGrossRemainder > 12) {
                    eggsDozen = eggsGrossRemainder / 12;
                    eggsDozenRemainder = eggsGrossRemainder % 12;
                    if (eggsDozenRemainder > 0){
                        eggsSingle = eggsDozenRemainder;
                        System.out.println("You have " + eggsGross + " gross amount of eggs, " + eggsDozen + " dozens mounts of eggs, and "
                                + eggsSingle + " remainder eggs.");
                        while1 = false;
                    }
                    System.out.println("You have " + eggsGross + " gross amount of eggs and " + eggsDozen + " dozens mounts of eggs.");
                    while1 = false;
                }
                System.out.println("You have " + eggsGross + " gross amounts of eggs.");
                while1 = false;
            }
            else if(eggNumber <= 144 && eggNumber >= 12){
                eggsDozen = eggNumber / 12;
                eggsDozenRemainder = eggNumber % 12;
                if (eggsDozenRemainder > 0){
                    eggsSingle = eggsDozenRemainder;
                    System.out.println("You have " + eggsDozen + " dozen eggs and " + eggsSingle + " remainders.");
                    while1 = false;
                }
                System.out.println("You have " + eggsDozen + " dozen eggs.");
                while1 = false;
            }
            else if (eggNumber > 0 && eggNumber < 12){
                eggsSingle = eggNumber;
                System.out.println("You have no Gross amounts or Dozen amounts, only " + eggsSingle + " singles.");
                while1 = false;
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("C'mon now... let's put a normal value in:");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you debugged the application to make sure you're right?

Comment: What is the value you entered ?

Comment: It'll continue until the next loop iteration. If you want to break out of the loop immediately, use `break`.

Comment: You really need to start breaking you code up into more methods. It will help you a lot to identify your errors.

Comment: Yeah, I can do that, thanks. I wanted to see how far I could stretch it though.

Answer (score 1):

turning the boolean to false, means the loop will not complete another turn, however it will continue along its path, i.e "47" eggs is>12 and less than "144", eggsDozenRemainder is >0 so that if block will run, however so will the block that follows as that if decision is not mutually exclusive, try If (){}else{}

Try a Control flow diagram http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow_diagram to help understand.